# Should errors in the question be edited, or left there for context?

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

I've recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2453444/cardinallity-of-the-set-of-continous-functions-x-to-y-when-space-x-is-sepa?noredirect=1#comment5069140_2453444) question. As pointed out correctly by one of the commenters, there is a (completely in context) error in my description. Also, my general attempt to solve the question I posted (as described in the question body) is either wrong, or confused and useless in the context of solving the question.

On one hand leaving the question 'as-is' keeps the correct context for the comments and answers, on the other hand - the question description contains wrong or unhelpful ideas.

Should I edit the question and remove the wrong \ unimportant parts?

Comment: One thing you can do is add a line at the end that says something like "EDIT: I'm sorry, I goofed on such and such," and maybe also use struck-out text to indicate parts that are wrong but which answers address.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If changing the body of the question invalidates answers that others have given, then it is a bad idea to change the body of the question. An answer indicates that someone read the question as-is and composed an answer for that question. To change the question is to create a large amount of confusion for future readers, and annoyance for your answerers.

In general, problems of this sort often sprout from some sort of fundamental misunderstanding, and resolutions to these sorts of misunderstandings can be very valuable for future visitors.

Having said that, if you have another question (perhaps the original intended question, for instance), then you should ask it as another question. Be sure to link to the previous question and explain what the difference is.

Sometimes, answerers answer the "intended" question instead of the actual question. In these cases, it is fine to edit the question. I also consider it totally free to edit the question (even partially changing the nature of the question) within the first five minutes of asking [a typo clause], but that's just my thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep the original context, don't change according what others say.

Original context reflects your understanding of question, so I don't think you should change that according to someone.

Ask the reason why they think context is in appropriate, I think that will help you better.